# Pasting Lines of Code onto Python Command Line

Tags: python, aptana

I am working in Aptana Studio and Python shell in the built-in terminal there. I am running some 
rather long snippets of code on the shell command line. I keep tripping over typos so is there 
a way to write all the code and copy and paste it onto the command line.

Comment: Can you run `ipython` in the terminal instead of the default `python`? If so, do that, and use the `%cpaste` magic function.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can copy and paste code into the terminal, *as long as complete definitions do not have blank lines in them*.

You can paste:

```
def foo(bar):
    print(bar)
    return bar
```

but not

```
def foo(bar):
    print(bar)

    return bar
```

because the interpreter interprets the empty line as the end of the definition of `foo`.

The same applies to class definitions and suites (`if`, `try`, `except`, `while`, `finally`, etc.); no blank lines allowed anywhere in attribute and function definitions.

Comment: +1, but I think you mean to say _do not have blank lines_, not _newlines_—obviously the first version has 3 newlines in it, and is perfectly fine.

Comment: So I cannot paste for loops and if-statements?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski is right; it's actually _complete statements_, not just _complete definitions_.

Comment: @Dombey: you can, but you cannot have blank lines in them.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not already configured that way, you may want configure your IDE to use [IPython](http://ipython.org/) as your interpreter.  With it, you can use the magic function `%cpaste` to allow you to paste full chunks of code.  Just end your chunk with a line containing only `--` to tell IPython that you're done.